# a regex for replacing everything except alphabets and numbers and space

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this expression,

```
$thing = "linkin park @#%^&* 999"; 
$thing = preg_replace('#\W#', '', $thing); 
echo $thing;
```

and it results to `linkinpark999`. I just need an expression which will result to `linkin_park_999`. It will be great if you explain me the code too.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good place to learn about regular expressions, and the [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) documentation is worth looking at as well.

Comment: thanks i am very bad when it comes to preg_replace...:P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
$thing = preg_replace('#\W+#', '_', $thing);
```

Comment: now what will i say. that was the fastest help i've ever got!...thanks a lot!